# Is there a need for a Facebook specific page title?

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, title, facebook-graph

I see that Facebook's Open Graph asks you to have a meta property "og:title".

Why don't they just use the HTML title tag?

In my PHP code I started going through all page types and coding the og:title property. Then I realized, why don't I just set the og:title to the HTML page title? It would probably save me a lot of work...

Am I missing something? In which cases would we want the og:title to be different?

Answer (score 2):

It's not *needed*, but it can be useful.
The important bit in defining the use of `og:title` is "as it should appear within the graph." In general, you want that to be the title of your blog post(or whatever). If your site's HTML titles are just that, then there's no real difference here.

On the other hand, many sites produce title tags that look like some combination of:

> Blog Post Title | PostCategory | Site Name | Site Blurb Here

…in which case all of that gets sent through as the Open Graph data.
This would be a case where you might want to set `og:title` to the post title, so that when something gets shared to Facebook, it comes through without all the clutter.

There are several potential cases, eg. on some sites a post's headline is entirely different from what ends up in the `title` tag, which will often be a more "SEO-friendly"/linkbait-y version. Here again you might want the `og:title` to be the true headline.